# Copy a column from one sheet and paste as row in another using application worksheetfunciton match in vba

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet-function

I have this excel file in Sheet1:

```
  A       B          C                       D
Brand   Model      Type           No_of_unit_sold
A       AB123        1                       1
A       AB124        1                       2
A       AB125        1                      11
A       AB113        1                      21
A       AB127        1                      42
A       AB128        1                      12
B       BB123        1                      21
B       BB121        1                      32
AB      BB122        2                      21
AB      BB124        1                      79
AB      BB125        2                      61
AB      BB126        1                      181
B       BB127        1                      28
B       BB128        1                      132
C       CB121        1                      91
C       CB122        1                      73
C       CB123        1                      63
C       CB124        1                      52
C       CB125        1                      85
A       AB129        2                      12
C       CB126        1                      13
C       CB128        1                      94
C       CB129        1                      121
```

I need the VBA to first scan column "Type" for type 1 only.

and then, to look for brand, copy brand A's name, sum up the number of unit sold and paste it in Sheet2:

```
 A                     B      C      D      E
Brand                  A      B      AB     C
No_of_unit_sold       89     213    260    592
```

To sum up the value, I can use sumif function with double criteria. But how do I vary the name of the brand? It's not like using for loop with integer like what I can do for "Type" column...

Also, how do I copy brand name from sheet1 to sheet2 without duplication?
Do I use application.worksheetfunction.match? Eg. if the brand name is not found in cells(1,i) of sheet2 then please copy from sheet1 to sheet2?

Comment: Is it possible to sort the column with "Brand" alphabetically before any vba is made? This makes it a lot easier if the duplicate brand categories follow each other :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code will works for you. I have used couple of `For` loops, `If` statement and `Function` to achieve this as am not knowledgeable with `application.worksheetfunction.match`. I tried as below and Worked for me!

Input sheet:

[image: input sheet]

Try the below code.

```
Sub VBAReader()

Dim CompareBrand As String
'Dim CompareBrands() As Variant
Dim Types, units, Units_sold, ValidatedBrands As Integer
Units_sold = 0
Dim Brand As String
Dim i, j, k, l As Integer
k = 2

Types = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row

For i = 2 To Types

'Give the type of value
If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & i).Value = 1 Then
Brand = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value

If BrandIsValidated(Brand) = False Then

For j = 2 To Types
If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & j).Value = Brand And Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & j).Value = 1 Then
units = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & j).Value
Units_sold = Units_sold + units
End If
Next

Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, k).Value = Brand
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, k).Value = Units_sold

Units_sold = 0
CompareBrand = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, k).Value

k = k + 1

End If

End If

Next

End Sub

Function BrandIsValidated(stringToBeFound As String) As Boolean

  ValidatedBrands = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
   For l = 1 To ValidatedBrands
   If stringToBeFound = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, (l + 1)).Value Then
   BrandIsValidated = True
   Exit For
   Else
   BrandIsValidated = False

   End If
   Next

End Function
```

Output sheet:

[image]

Note: I am new to VBA so my code wont be friendly. Edits are welcome :)

Comment: looks promising. I will try it out and let u know

Comment: Hi it works. But I also found a much shorter way to do it using For loops only. Thanks!

Comment: @MT32 Happy to hear it from you. If my answer fits your question please accept my answer :)